# Is there any way to pin a Chrome extension automatically when installing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. Recently I saw that when a chrome extension installed it's not showing in the toolbar. There is an extension toolbar icon. When I clicked that icon it shows all the installed extension then I need to pin those extensions which I want to show in the toolbar. Is there any way automatically pin my extension? So that the extension icon will be automatically visible in the toolbar. Because most of the users complaining that extension is not showing. On my extension when users click the toolbar icon it opens a popup.

Comment: No, there's no way.

Comment: I think that it is not possible, since they added the puzzle icon to "show more". Check this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028193/pin-chrome-extension-icon-by-default-programmatically).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** There is no way anymore to pin your chrome extension automatically.

Source:

> https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/62469131?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

No. For UI purposes Chrome has decided to make no way to pin your chrome extension. You can read more on the reasoning here:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/rOso__zU_sM/m/UTxbb5gnAgAJ