# Pin chrome extension icon by default programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension, is it possible to pin it's by default programmatically? with chrome api or with JS

I want that when a user downloads the extension it's icon will be pinned by default.

[image]

Comment: `is it possible to pin it by default programmatically?` no.

Comment: @Olian04 Do you have experience with developing chrome extensions?

Comment: Not possible. All extension developers world-wide are frustrated for the last month because of that.

Comment: @wOxxOm Why only for the last month? in the past it was possible? or you just joking

Comment: This puzzle piece menu appeared a few months ago and about a month ago it became impossible to disable via chrome://flags. Previously there was no need to pin anything as it was the default behavior.

Comment: why chrome extension Google Translate can do it

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately (for extension developers), it's not possible to do anymore. All extensions are unpinned by default. Here is an email thread about the topic in the Chromium Extensions mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/rOso__zU_sM/m/UTxbb5gnAgAJ?pli=1